# CSS animation for falling, vibrations, etc

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, bezier

I'm looking to animate objects moving realistically using pure CSS. Specifically:

1. something falling/bouncing
2. a vibrating string (simple harmonic motion/sinusoidal)
3. something falling through a fluid (from rest to terminal velocity)

As far as I'm aware, smooth animation in CSS can currently only be achieved through the use of cubic Bézier curves:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function

I figured out that falling can be modelled exactly by `cubic-bezier(0.33, 0, 0.66, 0.33)`, which together with `cubic-bezier(0.33, 0.66, 0.66, 1)` for the up-bounce can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/BYossarian/Frg74/2/

Does anyone know of the best Bézier curves for (2) and/or (3)?
And if anyone has any input on any other types of physical motion, that would be great too.

If needs be, I can eye-ball it, but I was hoping someone might have this already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I've been playing with this, and have vibrations done. As I expected, I had to piece together a bunch of Bézier curves in order to make it work:

http://jsfiddle.net/BYossarian/wrK44/6/    (webkit prefixes only)

The red ball is animated through CSS, and the gray box is animated using JS for reference.
Click the container to start/stop.

The CSS (without prefixes) for the animation is:

```
.vibrate {
    animation: shm 2s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes shm {
    from {
        margin-left:0px;
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.01, 0.55, 0.16);
    }
    25% {
        margin-left:29.3px;
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 0.44, 0.47, 0.44);
    }
    50% {
        margin-left:100px;
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.53, 0.56, 0.48, 0.56);
    }
    75% {
        margin-left:170.7px;
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.45, 0.84, 0.75, 0.99);
    }
    to {
        margin-left:200px;
    }
}
```

Couple of notes:

1. This starts from one edge, rather than the middle of the vibration. If you need to start in the middle, you can offset it using [animation-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay).
2. You can scale the distances up/down by multiplying them all by some constant and it should work.
3. The `animation-duration` given here is the time for the ball to move from one edge to the other (the return journey being covered by setting `animation-direction: alternate;`), so the time taken for the object to do a complete loop in the above is 4s.

UPDATE: Ok, so I finally found time to get fluid motion going on:

http://jsfiddle.net/S7WRp/  (again, webkit prefixes only)

Click to start. First ball is animated through JS. Second is the CSS animation. The third and fourth are both travelling at a constant speed (the terminal velocity of the other balls) and are used as reference so you can see the first two balls accelerating at the start, and then reaching terminal velocity at the end.

The CSS:

```
@keyframes fluidDrop {
    from {
        top: 0px;
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.22, 0.725, 0.61);
    }
    13.33% {
        top: 31.79px;
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.16, 0.1875, 0.24, 0.094);
    }
    23.66% {
        top: 88.3px;
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.234, 0.15, 0.88, 0.85);
    }
    65% {
        top: 441.5px;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
    to {
        top: 800px;
    }
}
```

Even more notes:

1. The shape of the object and the viscosity of the fluid will affect things here so I just went for an 'average' viscosity and a spherical object as a 'one size fits all'.
2. To use this, just set the time of the animation to whatever you need, and then scale the `top` values proportionally to match the distance you want your object to fall. Right now, it falls a distance of 800px, so if, for example, you wanted it to fall a distance of 1600px you would multiple all the `top` values from all the keyframes by 2.